# Modernizr detecting geolocation api not working

Tags: modernizr

I'm trying to get simple code for modernizr js to say whether or not a browser can support geolocation api. Here's my code.

```
 <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- check if geolocation works on browser -->
    <script>
    if(Modernizr.geolocation)
    {
    document.getElementById("geoConfirm").innerHTML = "This will work on this browser!";
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("geoConfirm").innerHTML = "This will not work on this browser";
    }


    </script>
    <p id="geoConfirm">Test</p>
```

It's such simple code but it's not working, and it's bugging me because there's barely anything to go over. Thoughts?

Comment: In what way is it not working? what browser are you testing?

Comment: I used chrome and firefox. The response messages do not show up, this tells me that something is wrong with how i wrote the code, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue. please share an example of the code being broken through jsbin or codepen or a similar code sharing site.